# R: Is it possible to put a text box so many cm/inches above a line in graph? (Whithout changing scale of graph)

Tags: r

Is it possible to put a text box so many cm/inches above a line in graph in R? (Whithout changing scale of graph). So im plotting the image using plot and i want to specify that the text using the function: text() but I always want the text to  be 1cm above the arrow at the specified x-coordinate.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hguuY.png)

Comment: You've left a lot of ambiguity here, including how you're creating your plot in the first place (are you using base `plot`, `ggplot2`...?). Please include some detail about exactly what you're trying to achieve, show what you've tried so far, and show specifically what it is about your code that isn't quite right.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply with `?text`. So not entirely with cm's but if you know the range of your data you can position your text as data points in the plot.

## Example:

Let's make some test data.

```
dat <- matrix(rnorm(3*4), ncol=2)
colnames(dat) <- c("v1", "v2")
```

Create a scatter plot. You can of course apply `text` to any graphical plot, but I'm keeping it simple.

```
plot(v2 ~ v1, data = dat)
```

And now just create a line, in whatever direction. I'll just go with an abline at `height` 1.0 on the `y-axis`

```
abline(h=1.0)
text(1,1,"this is an abline", pos = 1)
```

With text I add text on position 1,1 (x, y) in the plot. I adjust it with `pos` so It doesn't get crossed by the abline.

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I just edited my original question and hopefully it is more clear now

Comment: If you want your text to always be above the line, then the same applies. Just use `pos = 2`. For more info on how to position text I recommend reading the `?text` help.